# Verifying connector direction

Tags: pcb, connector

I cleaned very old mouse which has some corrosion in one battery spring connector but no damage on circuit board.
While disassembling, the connector of battery box did not separate from the connector on circuit board but came together with the wire. I am not sure which way the connector was. There is no clear markings near the pads.
I have multimeter but the head of it is quite big and I did not find good place to check continuity to some known + or ground point on PCB. Attached is the picture of the region around the connector (J2).
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you would post an image of the loose connector that is still attached to the battery connector, it might be obvious. From this picture, it is impossble to tell which is positive and negative. The connector will, however, will seem to only fit in one correct orientation.

Comment: The picture is too bad and too incomplete to give a direct advise. Usually it goes like this: TVS or polarized cap close to the connector are dead certain placed between + and -. If you don't have that, then ceramic caps are in most cases always placed between + and - or between a signal and -. So just by measuring the resistance between different pads of various unrelated caps, you will be able to find ground. The only time when ceramic caps don't come with a grounded pad is in RF and analog circuits - if it's a wireless mouse then be aware of this.

Comment: The left-most ceramic cap on the picture is dead certain some bulk cap on the supply, 1uF to 10uF or the like. One pad on the + trace and one pad on PCB ground. The + trace is very likely the thick one coming out from the connector towards that cap.

Comment: I took two new images without zoom. Battery compartement and half of the PCB.

Comment: @TonyVeijalainen To clarify, J2 is the connector that became disattached from the PCB and you're wondering in what direction it was soldered to the PCB? But J2 is a surface mount right angle connector, it only has one possible direction it fits on the PCB. Or are you asking about the direction of the plug in the socket?

Comment: the female part of the jst plug was soldered there. There is no through hole place for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that two of the test pads had connection to each side of the battery connector location. Right down one to down connector and left down pad to upper connector pad. So I think to attach wire to each of them as they are much bigger than the pitch of the connector (seems to me 1.5 mm).[image] Then I can attach the female connector that wire after verifying polarity.